# How to call services dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I have 20 different services (factory). Each service execute one rule when action perform.
Based on the ruleCode I want to call a specific service. 
What I am doing is, I have another service called ActionHandler that contains a SWITCH statement based on the CASE it calls a specific service. To do this I have injected all the 20 services in ActionHandler Service.

I don't think this is a best practice

Can anyone please suggest me the best approach solving this kind of issue.

Thanks in Advance ::

```
angular.forEach(List, function (elem) {
        switch (elem.ruleCode){
            case 'a':{
              callAService();
                break;
            }
            case 'b':{
                callBService();
                break;
            }
            //similarly others case
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are several approaches. First that comes to mind (maybe a bit hacky):

If there's a match between the `elem.ruleCode` and the service name, you could use `$injector` to get the service based on it's name. Something like:
 `$injector.get(elem.ruleCode + 'RuleService').foo()`. Of course this requires that all your services have a method called `foo()`.

For example if your `elem.ruleCode` can have the values a or b, you would have 2 services:
`aRuleService` and `bRuleService`, each one with a method `foo()`.